# ORA-01017 logon denied/invalid username

Tags: oracle, visual-studio-2022, ora-01017

i was able to connect to my database using sql plus and modify database schema(like update , delete tables and do querying), but when i try to connect it using visual studio im getting ORA-01017 error , i double checked my connection string and every credential(user id and password) im passing is correct. wondering what could be the issue! anyone faced simlar issue , do help me out

I tried connecting but wasnt able to connect

Comment: It could be your password isn't correct, or needs to be wrapped in double-quotes, or shouldn't be (if visual studio does that for you), or isn't the correct case, or a client version compatibility issue or setting on the server. Lots of possibilities. You should reach out to your DBA.

Comment: Please check if you have both the applications in the same infrastructure